# Power drill motor with no electronics?

Tags: motor, ac, drill

I have a Bosch power drill, the same as in [this other question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167556/how-does-the-circuit-of-a-basic-variable-speed-electric-drill-work)

I checked it carefully and it doesn't seem to have a capacitor or any other electronic components.

1. Does it mean the universal motor in it runs directly with the 240VAC?
2. Does it also mean that the rotational speed of the drill is 60Hz?
3. Can someone explain to me how that is possible? (I am new to electronics.)

Comment: take the trigger mech apart, that's where you'll find them

Comment: Basically, the trigger has a triac inside. This question has been answered here already: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167556/how-does-the-circuit-of-a-basic-variable-speed-electric-drill-work

Comment: If you have an old single speed drill, yes this could be the case.

Comment: 1. Yes it is a universal motor. 2. No the speed is related to voltage rather than frequency. 3. A universal motor is like a series DC motor. You should be able to find on the internet a nice detailed explanation of a universal motor with illustrations. The question you linked shows how the electronics of a variable speed motor might be hard to recognize. Comments in that question tell a little more about universal motors. Also check other questions with the [universal-motor] tag.

Comment: I see No electrronic component in the trigger. It has two inlet leads (live n neutral) n 2 out leads ( one wire to each field coil) .    the other field cables are connected to the direction switch . each brush has one wire connected to the direction switch.

Comment: @Huisman no it doesnt  . my drill is not working n i am trying to diagnose the problem

Comment: @RonBeyer i think that is the case . i opened the trigger box n i didnt see any electronics

Comment: @Neil_UK taken the trigger apart . still       no electronic component

Comment: Are your brushes in good shape? This is in the motor itself.

Comment: As Charles Cowie said, it's not at all necessary for there to be electronics in the drill, we had electric drill long before electronics were small enough to be put into one... Even if it is variable speed, the trigger need only be a simple rheostat. If it's not working, the chances are that the brushes are bad, or the commutator (the part the brushes connect to) has loaded up with debris.